# Get an image from LinkedIn API without receiving entire CDN dump

Tags: linkedin-api

Although the LinkedIn API claims it is rebuild with developers in mind, I struggle to get any meaningful image from the API without retrieving ~7000 response lines. Here's an example request trying to retrieve the profile picture:

```
curl -XGET <LinkedInURL>/me&projection=profilePicture(displayImage~digitalmediaAsset:playableStreams) <AUTH Headers>
```

This simple request returnes a complete CDN dump of about 7000 lines of code defining the image in all possible aspect ratios. As I'm working with more and more API endpoints, I'm stuggling to work with this gigantic response object and am unsure if I'm doing something wrong here?

Is there a more straighforward way to retrieve an image from the API?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
curl -XGET <LinkedInURL>/me?projection=(profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams(croppedImageUrl))) <AUTH Headers>
```

Comment: This returns no value for the image. I'm also unable to find the docs on `croppedImageUrl` in the LinkedIn API docs.